# recvmmsg remains blocked on CTRL-C

Tags: c, linux, signals, recvmmsg

I am using `recvmmsg` to read from a blocking UDP socket out of a mutlicast group.

In the man pages of that API I noted that the errors messages don't mention EINTR so it looks like that api cannot catch when a signal has been received.

I tested and I can see that if I issue a CTRL-C when `recvmmsg` is blocked waiting on some data to read nothing happens and it remains blocked.

Do you know why this is happening and how to catch the signal correctly?

I am using Linux CentOs 7 and Oracle Linux

Comment: I don't know the answer to your specific question but wanted to point out that the man page does mention EINTR. It just does do by reference rather than directly: "Errors  are  as  for  recvmsg(2).....". And `recvmsg` lists EINTR as one of the errors.

Comment: The default action for `SIGINT` is to terminate; if that doesn't happen, it means you're either blocking `SIGINT` or changed the default disposition. Can you show the code where you do that? You might be going about it the wrong way.